# how to detect if inside a LaTeX math environment?

Tags: latex, auctex

**Q:** is there a way to detect if point is inside a LaTeX math environment?

How would one detect whether point is or is not inside a LaTeX math environment, whether delineated inline by `$...$` or by named environments (`equation`, `displaymath`, etc.)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `texmathp` defined in AUCTeX (autoloaded from [`texmathp`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/texmathp.el)) does exactly that (ok, actually it does a bit more).

Used interactively, it will give you some more information, including whether the point is in a math construct.

Used in elisp, it will be `t` if in math, `nil` otherwise. The additional pieces of informations are then stored in the variable `texmathp-why`.

When `texmathp` returns `t`, this is a cons of `(MATCH . POSITION)`, where `MATCH` is a string containing the TeX command or the name of the environment that triggered math mode, and `POSITION` is the position at which that string was found in the buffer. `MATCH` is something like `"$"`, `"$$"`, `"\\("`, `"\\["` `"\\ensuremath"`, `"displaymath"`, `"equation"`, … When `texmathp` returns `nil`, the variable `texmathp-why` is `(nil . pos)` where `pos` is the beginning of the paragraph.

Warning from the docstring:

> The functions assumes that you have (almost) syntactically correct (La)TeX in
>   the buffer.

It is aware of all environments that `AUCTeX` knows of (for example for font-locking), and you can add more using the variable `texmathp-tex-commands`.

Comment: Also note that (shameless self-promotion ahead) this command is very convenient when mixed with emacs regular expressions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91175/9517

Comment: Self-promotion is an afterthought when sharing useful and relevant information :)