# How to force the variable 'bidi-paragraph-direction' taking the value 'left-to-right' in a math environment in LaTeX-mode

Tags: latex, auctex, bidirectional-support

One of the great features of Emacs is its ability to handle bidirectional support for the right-to-left languages (like Hebrew, Arabic and Persian). Note that even in these languages mathematical formulae are written from left-to-right. So when typing a mathematical formula (usually between $ $) in a right-to-left line, it would be desirable to temporary force the direction left-to-right. For example in the following line I have written $V^*$ but Emacs shows it in reverse.

[image]

I know the setting `(setq bidi-paragraph-direction 'left-to-right)` can be used to change to the correct direction. Also the variable `texmathp` can be used to determine if the cursor is in a math environment (see [how to detect if inside a LaTeX math environment?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/547/2609) and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/548/2609).

But I don't know to put these altogether. So my question is

**How to force the direction from right-to-left in a math environment?**

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I found a solution: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38464/limit-the-scope-of-bidirectional-display-to-single-line

Answer (score 2):

The variable `bidi-paragraph-direction` is not the answer to your problem, since it affects the whole buffer.  Instead if you want to change the directionality of a particular piece of text, you'll need to insert special control characters.

E.g. you could insert an LRM (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) character just before the opening `$` and another just after the closing `$`.

I don't know what TeX will do with such characters, tho.  AFAIK there is currently no way in Emacs to insert such characters only for the display via something like a `display` property or an `after-string` overlay (i.e. not as part of the buffer's content).  You might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug` requesting a new feature for that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think Emacs can insert LR mark using quail package for example by setting ("&lrm;" ?\u200E) when using a particular input-method. Perhaps I make a mistake.