# Limit the scope of bidirectional display to single line

Tags: bidirectional-support

I have set the variable `bidi-paragraph-direction` to `nil` in my `init.el` so that lines starting with (strong) Arabic letters are displayed from right to left, and lines with English are displayed from left to right.

It works fine except that I have to insert an empty line between lines with different directionality so that the next line won't be affected by the previous line directionality. I'm not sure if this is a bug or an expected behavior:

```
أبجد هوز
ABCD

*******************************************

أبجد هوز

ABCD
```

[image: Problem illustration]

Is there a way to limit the scope of directionality to a single line? or redefine the number of lines in a single paragraph? (GTK+ is doing it right).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to want to set both `bidi-paragraph-start-re` and `bidi-paragraph-separate-re` to `"^"`:

```
(setq bidi-paragraph-separate-re "^"
      bidi-paragraph-start-re "^")
```

The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Bidirectional-Display.html) for these variables says:

> If you change the value of this variable, be sure to change
>   the value of ‘bidi-paragraph-separate-re’ accordingly.  **For
>   example, to have a single newline behave as a paragraph separator,
>   set both these variables to "^".**

I don't know much about Emacs's bidirectional display, but I found these variables and the above line in the documentation by using `describe-variable` with [`helm-mode`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) and searching for "bidi" after I suspected there might be a built in way to control this behavior. You can also use the built in `M-x` commands `apropos` and `apropos-variable` and friends to search for variables and functions that might be relevant.

Comment: This does not seem to work (I am using emacs 25). <del>Are you using emacs 26?</del> OK, these controls were introduced in [emacs 26](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/NEWS.26#L623).

Comment: @user6026299, Ah, yes I am! Sorry about that!

Comment: I have compiled and installed emacs 26, it works like charm :)!