# Change bidi direction for specific characters in buffer

Tags: faces, bidirectional-support

I use Emacs to write LaTeX, and ran into the same problem as in [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5731/how-to-force-the-variable-bidi-paragraph-direction-taking-the-value-left-to-r), and for now I do as suggested in the questions answer. I've created some macros for making the process of adding the control characters more streamlined, however, I would want to be able to get rid of those characters entirely.

I want to develop some plugin that will find `$` pairs, and make Emacs display them as LTR. I think if Emacs had a `text-direction` attribute for faces,  that would be a good solution, however its seems that doesn't exist. The next best thing I can think of is make Emacs display selected characters as two characters in the buffer (in my case that would be to present a `$` as a `$` and a control character), but my intuition tells me that won't affect the  bidi algorithm.

Any ideas for how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you already tried customizing the variables `bidi-directional-controls-chars` and `bidi-directional-non-controls-chars`?  According to the doc-string of `bidi-paragraph-direction` ... "*If this is nil (the default), the direction of each paragraph is
determined by the first strong directional character of its text. ...*"

Comment: You might also want have a look inside `xdisp.c`; e.g., a comment that says ... "*Characters in unibyte strings are always treated by bidi.c as strong LTR*".  And likewise, look inside `bidi.c` ...

Comment: The question is too broad. Please pose only one question per post - a specific question. E.g. how to do <something specific>.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs uses the `bidi-class` property of the character when it reorders bidirectional text for display. See [Character Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Properties.html) in the elisp manual.

To check the `bidi-class` of a specific character, here `$`:

```
(get-char-code-property ?$ 'bidi-class) ;; ET
```

To get a description of what is `ET`:

```
(char-code-property-description 'bidi-class 'ET) ;; "European Number Terminator"
```

Also see [UAX #9: Bidirectional Character Types](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Table_Bidirectional_Character_Types)

To change the `bidi-class` of a specific character, for example to change `$`  to be a strong left-to-right character:

```
(put-char-code-property ?$ 'bidi-class 'L)
```

You might experiment with other values, but the above works for me.