# Detection inside general LaTeX (not necessarily Math) commands

Tags: latex, auctex

This question is related to [how to detect if inside a LaTeX math environment?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/547/2609).

How to do the correct settings in `.emacs` in such a way that the variable `texmathp` takes the value `t` (like in math formulae) when the cursor is at the following commands?

```
\newpage ;command for creating a new page
\label{blabla}
\cite{blabla}
\ref{blabla}
\footnote{blabla}
\section{blabla}
\chapter{blabla}
\\ ;command for creating a new line
```

In the [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/548/2609) it was mentioned that one can use `texmathp-tex-commands` to achieve such things. Let me ask how to do it for the above formulae.

Comment: `TeX-current-macro` returns the name of the current macro point is on, is it what you need?

Comment: @giordano Let me say no, I just want a Boolean variable which tells me if I am at a LaTeX command (like `texmathp` for math formulae). T. Verron says in that answer that one can do such things with `texmathp` by adding new values to `texmathp-tex-commands`. I just want to see how to do it.

Comment: Why do you want to abuse texmathp? TeX-current-macro is there for that reason, returns the name of the macro if there is one at point, nil otherwise, so it can be used as a boolean.

Comment: Thanks @giordano I am now persuaded that your approach is far better than what I had in mind. Could you please convert your comment to an answer in order that I may be able to mark it as accepted (for example printing the message in the echo area "Inside LaTeX environment" if `TeX-current-macro` is non-nil otherwise printing "Outside LaTeX environment").

Comment: Uh, did you mean "macro" instead of "environment"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `TeX-current-macro`.  Here is an example of how you can use it to print a message depending on whether point is inside or outside a TeX macro:

```
(defun mg-TeX-current-macro-p ()
  (interactive)
  (if (TeX-current-macro)
      (message "Inside a LaTeX macro")
    (message "Outside a LaTeX macro")))
```