# Use all the codes in the existed equations as the backend for autocompletion when type new equation

Tags: latex, auctex, completion, company-mode

I find that I often have to suffer typing some similar latex codes many times in different equations or the same equation. So it will be convenient that all the codes in the existed equations in the buffer could be used as the backend for autocompletion.

It seems to me that it should be the same technique  used in the autocompletion for the plain text. That is,

1. collect all the codes/words separated by space  in the buffer as the backend
2. list the candidates with the same beginning

It's great if some superuser can implement this. Any comments or suggestions are also welcome.

PS: I already use [cdlatex](https://github.com/cdominik/cdlatex) for symbol completion. As I tested, [company-auctex](https://github.com/alexeyr/company-auctex) didn't list the codes in the existed equations.

Comment: The function `texmathp` defined in AUCTeX (autoloaded from [`texmathp`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/texmathp.el)) could detect whether point is or is not inside a LaTeX math environment. Please look at [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/548/16331) for details.